# Problem with session ID and Drupal cookies when trying to establish a connection

Tags: services, 8

I tried to established a connection between my app and Drupal services.
When I try to login to remote Drupal site using Mozilla add-on Poster everything is working... POST request return OK 200 and I'm logged into the site.

When I make the POST request from my app, I always get 200 repose OK, but when I visit the site in browser I'm not logged in.
I suppose that Cookie header is not correctly structured in POST request...but I don't know how to fix it.

Does anyone have idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Drupal 8. The AJAX POST isn't retrieving the cookie from `user/login` as Drupal does a redirect right away to another page (`user` usually) which is where you get your 200. And there is nothing (*nothing*) you can do to interrupt that redirect as its wired into the browser. Postman in Chrome (and I presume Poster in Firefox) don't have those restrictions.

In Drupal 7 the Services module provides a login endpoint. After that you can retrieve the session ID and create the cookie by hand. See https://groups.drupal.org/node/358308

In Drupal 8 that endpoint doesn't exist (and there is debate as to whether it should). What I do is:

1. In the app I create a regular login form with a return destination to my app
   `<form action="/user/login?destination=/app">`
2. Once that's done I retrieve a CSRF token as by then the cookie is set. In Drupal 8 you get that at `rest/session/token`. With Drupal 7 and the Services module you retrieve it at a different path based on your end point.
3. After that every request goes back with the *X-CSRF-Token* header and the cookie isn't used anymore.

Comment: Hi, I use Drupal 7. I get the session cookie with the POST request from my app, but when I load the remote site in browser I'm not logged in.

Comment: Like I say. The cookie isn't set and stored in the browser. You have to pass it in on every POST with custom headers.

Comment: Hi thank you. I don't need to make any authorized post request after I'm logged in. I just need to redirect to remote site and be logged in there.                           I tried to make a redirect with cUrl to the remote site with the cookie .. and it was working .. I was redirected to remote site as logged in user, but if I click on another location I'm not logged in anymore.It seems that only the first redirect is authorized. Any idea?

Comment: You can't set a cookie for a domain that you're not on. So what you're trying to do won't work. Try creating a regular form who's action points at the foreign domain as I mentioned in the answer. That should set a cookie in the correct domain.

Comment: Thank you. It's much clear now. But how will I combine the services endpoint and the form's action url? I must first post request to endpoint and after that redirect to foreign site? How I'll combine that two? Can you post some simple code example? Thank you.